# Can I change the data type of my primary key on a temporal table?

Tags: sql-server, alter-table, alter-column

In SQL Server 2016 Express, I initially made a table with a primary key that used the int datatype. Now, further into the project, I've realized that I need this column to be a string datatype, but when I try this:

```
alter table ExpAwbs
drop constraint PK_ExpAwbs;

alter table ExpAwbs
alter column idExpAwbs varchar(12);

alter table ExpAwbs
add constraint PK_ExpAwbs primary key (idExpAwbs);
```

I get this

```
Msg 4902, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot find the object "ExpAwbs" because it does not exist or you do not have permissions.
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do on a temporal table, or do I need to remake the table?

Comment: Are you in the correct database where that table resides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
Use YourDatabaseName
Go

alter table ExpAwbs
drop constraint PK_ExpAwbs;

alter table ExpAwbs
alter column idExpAwbs varchar(12);

alter table ExpAwbs
add constraint PK_ExpAwbs primary key (idExpAwbs);
```

If this not working that mean that the user do not have permissions, So you have to change the user or `Grant` the permission for that user.

Comment: That's odd. This worked, but the database server only has one user, and that's the admin user. But, I got a different error now that I cannot drop the primary key constraint from a system-versioned temporal table. I assume this means that what I'm trying to do can't be done.

Comment: Actually, turning of system versioning allowed me to drop the primary key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

As @wei_dba mentioned, it most certainly seems to be a permission issue. To prove that, I recreated your table, added some data to it and tried it - it worked. If you're unable to do so, clearly the issue lies within the area of permissions; you may need to have someone run that query for you.
While reviewing your query, I see another issue with a quick fix. You may want to replace the following:

```
alter table ExpAwbs  
alter column idExpAwbs varchar(12);
```

with

```
alter table ExpAwbs  
alter column idExpAwbs varchar(12) not null;
```

Reasoning being that you need to make sure that the PK is non-nullable, something which you haven't put into your query.